# When booting ubuntu, it states: thinkpad_acpi: Unsupported brightness interface

Tags: brightness, lenovo, ideapad

As the title says, when I boot my pc to Ubuntu (14.04), it says something like this:

[   23.025150] thinkpad_acpi: Unsupported brightness interface, please contact ibm-acpi-devel@...

And this confused me, because I'm not using a ThinkPad (I am using a Lenovo Ideapad y500 however). I was wondering if this thinkpad_acpi should even be installed on my system? And if not, how can I remove it?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem on my E540.
Take a look at this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1389456

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lenovo bought the IBM pc division about 10 years ago.  I'm on a Lenovo thinkpad which was the original IBM notebook.  I get the same error but brightness control seems to work fine.

I'm new to Linux myself, but I do believe that the generic acpi functions work fine.  What needs to happen is the drivers need to be written to recognize the acpi hardware that Lenovo has.  Could be wrong on that one.